# String Manipulation in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have the following scenarios:

1. str = "Upper Left 1 Upper Left 2"

I want the result to be newStr = "Upper Left 1 and 2"

2. str = "Upper Left 8 Upper Left 8"

I want the result to be newStr = "Upper Left 8"

3. str = "Upper Left 5 Upper Right 9"

I want the result to be newStr = "Upper Left 5 Upper Right 9"

I tried replace, distinct and split but none seem to do what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Lot's of ideas; too many to list in-fact. Show us the code that you tried so we can narrow it down.

Comment: Well, without really knowing the limitations / possibilities for the strings, it is quite hard to define an answer. You could simply split them by whitespace, check if the first corresponds the half, and the second corresponds to the half + 1, if they do, you know you can use the `and` syntax or if all of the one half match, then you can keep the half of the text and if not you can use the string as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, there are many ways to do this. What is the best one depends on how many cases you have. I'd do it like this:

```
Dim partList as List(Of String) = str.Split(" ").toList()
if(partList.item(1) = partList.item(4) AndAlso partList.item(2) = partList.item(5)) Then
    newStr = partList.item(0) + partList.item(1) + partList.item(2)
elseif(partList.item(1) = partList.item(4)) Then
    newStr = partList.item(0) + partList.item(1) + partList.item(2) + " and "+ partList.item(5)
else
    newStr = str
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

DrDonut's approach is more compact than mine, but we're both just brute-forcing it. :)

```
Sub Main()
    Dim text As New List(Of String)
    text.Add("Upper Left 1 Upper Left 2")
    text.Add("Upper Left 8 Upper Left 8")
    text.Add("Upper Left 5 Upper Right 9")
    Dim output() As String
    For Each t As String In text
        Dim words() As String = t.Split(" ")
        ReDim output(words.Length)

        If words(0) = words(3) And words(1) = words(4) Then
            If words(2) = words(5) Then
                ' coordinates are the same
                Array.Copy(words, output, 3)
            Else
                ' quadrants are the same, but coords are different
                Array.Copy(words, output, 2)
                output(2) = words(2)
                output(3) = "and"
                output(4) = words(5)
            End If
        Else
            ' different quadrants
            Array.Copy(words, output, 6)
        End If
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", output))
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```